# Java Layoutmanagers & WindowBuilder Pro

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm having the problem that I don't like the way all layout managers position elements for the whole window.

I'm using the [WindowBuilder Pro](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/download.php) plugin for Eclipse to design the gui.

Either I support resizing of the window and use a layout manager (crappy positioning) or I choose the absolute one which allows me to place everything wherever I want but it's non-resizable and hard to maintain.

What's the trick in getting what you want using layout managers? How can I keep more control of the placements? Using panels and nested layout managers?

Comment: `What's the trick in getting what you want using layout managers?` do it yourself and don't rely on an IDE. For one thing the code is not portable if you ever change IDE's. `Using panels and nested layout managers?` Yes.

Comment: Please restate your question *clearly*. What particular problem you are having?